# Is it possible to config a remote git repository directly from command line?

Tags: git, remote-server, git-config

I wonder is there any method to change the configuration of a remote git repository without having a local clone? I prefer to pass the repo url into `git config`, but it seems that it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have access to the machine, you can update the .git/config file remotely (via ssh for instance)

Comment: No, the point is that I do not have access to the remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will only allows you to configure your repo if you work in a local clone. So you can't do this directly in a remote repo. In addition, you can also set a remote repo for your project with:

```
git remote add origin https://yourRepoUrl
```

But this is only for `push` and `fetch` operations, not for `config`.

Comment: But adding a remote repo using 'git remote add' is only for pushing and fetching not for changing the configuration. :(

Comment: Yep which config do you want to change ?

Comment: enable non-fast-forward merging.

Comment: I believe you cannot set this option server side, because the merges are always done client side